# How to increment the empid with python in text file

Tags: python

I have one text file in that there is two columns are available which names  'empid' and 'name'. Here  I want to increment the empid with 1(one) incremental value eachtime  means 10 times and name column will be repeatedly same. Here is the text file and python file

demo.txt file

```
empid   name

10      bhuvi
```

read_file.py file

```
fil = open('c:/users/$$$$$$/desktop/demo.txt','r')
fil2 = fil.read()
for  i in fil2:
     print(fil2[i],end='')
fil.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question, are you trying to append new rows to demo.txt like this?

demo.txt

```
empid, name
10, bhuvi
11, bhuvi
.., .....
20, bhuvi
```

If yes, then

```
with open('1.txt', 'r+') as f:
lines = f.readlines()
empid, name = lines[1].rsplit(',')
for i in range(1, 11):
    f.write(f'{int(empid) + i},{name}')
```